# C#, Getting user value and resetting it

Tags: c#, if-statement

Right now  my problem is getting choice 2 to save and rewrite what was written in choice 1.
Choice 3 should then reset everything.
Right now i tried with at if inside an if and still not getting it to work.

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\tWelcome to my program"); // Makes the user select a choice
    Console.WriteLine("[1] To write");
    Console.WriteLine("[2] To see what you wrote");
    Console.WriteLine("[3] Reset");
    Console.WriteLine("[4] End");

    string choice = Console.ReadLine();
    string  typed = ("");

    if (choice == "1") // If 1 program asks for text
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thank you for your choice, input text"); 
        typed = Console.ReadLine(); 
    }
    else if (choice == "2") // Is supposed to say "You wrote, and what user wrote"
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typed);
    }                            
    else if (choice == "3") //  Resets the text so if 2 is selected it would say "You wrote,     "
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Reset. Would you like to try again?");
        typed = "";
    }
    else if (choice == "4") // Ends program
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input not computing, try again");
    }
```

Comment: `string  typed = ("");` Remove that to outside the loop.

Comment: Think of the scope of your variable.  This loop effectively resets that variable everytime its run.  What if the variable was declared outside of the loop?...

Comment: A good **[Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)** will help you find such things very easily ***and*** improve your coding skills

Answer (score 5):

Your issue is as follows.

First, you are looping your entire program through a `while (true)` loop. Once the user choice is made, the program will go back to the `while (true)`. Note also that `string typed` is defined inside the loop. Therefore, every time the loop is called (which is every choice made), the program resets the value of 'typed'.

To fix this, introduce `string typed` outside the loop.

```
string typed = "";

while (true)
{
    //choices and stuff goes back here
}
```

Edit: I noticed this comment of yours `//Is supposed to say "You wrote, and what user wrote` on choice 2. Note that your code in choice 2 won't output `"You wrote" + typed`. To correct that, change `Console.WriteLine(typed);` to `Console.WriteLine("You wrote, " + typed);`.

Comment: Thank you SO much. Tried it and now it works perfectly